# Apple Lightning to Micro USB

Tags: ipad, usb, lightning

I am in the process of wiring up some iPad carts but they bought keyboards for the iPads that need to be charged by Micro USB.

The cart is already wired for Apple's Lightning and was wondering, is there anything aside from re-wiring the cart to go from the male Lightning connector to Micro USB or maybe the male Lightning to female USB so I can plug in the Micro USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

The only official Lightning / Micro USB adapter sold by Apple is the [Lightning to Micro USB adapter](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD820ZM/A/lightning-to-micro-usb-adapter) as shown below:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be an adapter for the reverse of this.

Comment: i seen that...i definitely need the reverse of this...not sure why no one has made it yet.